# How to set up an end-to-end SNMP data collection system?

Tags: snmp

**Aim:** We are creating a cloud server which will collect diagnostic data (like bytes exchanged, SNR) from remote SNMP enabled network devices (like Routers, Switches).

The SNMP devices may be located in a private network.

We discussed with a cable vendor who quoted,

> SNMP on modems is only accessible via the modem IP, which is
>   traditionally a private IP within an MSO. Companies will generally
>   deploy a probe or agent on-site that collects the SNMP data and
>   delivers it back to their main operation.
>
> SNMP proxies are also a possibility.

He talks about about *deploy probes, proxing, on site agent*.

We want to know how those mechanisms are actually implemented in detail.

Some references or few lines of introduction about the set up would be really helpful.

**Edit:** We are looking for answers from the perspective of developers of a network monitoring tool.

Comment: This question doesn't have one correct answer, and thus really isn't suited well for this site.

Answer (score 0):

PRTG is a great example of this.  What you are describing is how I architect my networks for resiliency.  I host my main monitoring server cluster on AWS EC2 and have 'probes' at each site that sit behind the site firewalls, gather SNMP data and send it to the core.

A probe is simply a computer gathering data.  Using SNMP version 2c, you will point the probes at the device ip's you want to monitor and they will gather the data and push to your 'cloud server' for reporting.

If you have questions, ping me.  I am happy to help or have a conversation about best practices in this arena.

Comment: Thank you Travis for the response.

Yes, we came across PRTG, I assume it is what AXIROS is, to TR069.

We find SNMP quite conservative in terms of accessibility contrary to TR069; which can be accessed using STUN even if the CPE is in a private network.
SNMP doesn't support this.

Though the implementation of TR069 clients is till date incomplete and unreliable.

So, in practice,
Is each household device connected to a probe?
Is the probe inside home private network?
Does probe send data to the cloud?

We are in the experimentation phase, so any references or links would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your original question, for me anyway, doesn't tell me if you are the end user managing a wan or small provider or developing a monitoring product.

snmp and TR069 are completely unrelated to each other in method, protocols and ports used. Can't compare to each other.

snmp probe is just that, a node be it a server, or pc on the inside polling all of the desired devices gathering information that it then forwards on to the central collector. In your case that is the cloud server.

Snmp can be setup to poll the wan port of the public ip devices but that is up to each device to support. Really only something I would consider if the public ip's are static and I have ACL's protecting what can snmp poll the devices wan ports. Can be done with dynamic dns but but can be problematic if the the device gets handed an updated ip then there is lag until dynamic dns updates. Again the CPE has to support dynamic dns.

You asked for links to documentation that more fully explains what your MSO mention. This link includes diagrams and links to the specific RFC's.

http://www.snmp.com/protocol/proxyinfo.shtml

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks bsulli for sharing your comments.
We are developing a network monitoring solution (added as an edit in queston).
If the SNMP enabled device's public IP changes, is there any way that it shall notify via TRAP to the collector or the SNMP manager?
Any such notification indicator exists?

Comment: Depends on several factors, 1.) does the CPE support generating the trap needed? That depends on the mibs the vendor imbedded in the product. Check their datasheet for list of mibs supported 2.) traps are a result of change of environment so the trap would happen after the change if supported and could send trap. The way to find out if the CPE supports the traps desired is to pull down the mibs from the CPE vendor and use a snmpwalk tool  http://www.net-snmp.org/ Sounds like you are duplicating this product. http://www.logicmonitor.com/ Not endorsing the product. Just referencing it.

Comment: We are more like experimenting with things.
A long way before actually duplicating. :P
Instead we are trying out naive means, like not browsing too much about the existing products and having more of a bottom up approach by exploring various known protocols and devices.
Reading technical papers; we are willing to take the country road.
This way we can grow fundamentally and might explore some new and better algorithm to do things.
Simply put, on the mission of IoT exploration ;)